# Setting "Build Active Architectures Only" To "YES" Pros vs Cons?

Tags: ios, iphone

I understand that setting this value to YES speeds up the building time. But as far as I know setting this option to "YES" will build for connected device's architecture.

So if I had connected an older device such as iPhone 3GS (ARMv7) release build should work on ARMv7, ARMv7s and ARM64.

But what happens if I release with a iPhone 5 (ARMv7s) connected while  "Build Active Architectures Only" set to "YES"  ?  I can assume build will work on ARMv7s and ARM64, but will it work on older devices which has ARMv7?

Comment: It just speeds up building/deploying during debug when you're testing on a device.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I don't think Apple will let you submit the app that way, but if you distribute it in other ways, it won't work on older devices...
That's why it's usually set as YES for Debug and NO for Release

Answer (score 5):

**Pro:** Building is faster since it builds only for your device architecture.

**Cons:** Your distribution build won't work on 32-bit architecture devices (iPhone 4s/5). So when you create a Distribution configuration for publishing to the App Store you should make sure this option is not set so that you build the fat universal binary.